# NOT IN (subquery) producing zero rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I keep finding examples where processes that utilise the formulation

```
WHERE a NOT IN (SELECT b FROM x)
```

are just returning zero rows which seems wrong. If I change NOT IN to IN it doesn't return the inverse (all rows), in fact it leaves out all the rows where a is not null.
This has started happening in overnight routines that have run fine for years and haven't been changed. It feels like there's a bug in SQL Server.

I can fix the problem by reformulating to

```
LEFT JOIN x on a = b
WHERE b IS NULL
```

but it's not something I want to have to live with.

Could it be something to do with statistics? A known bug? In the most recent example the table in the subquery is on a remote linked server though I'm not sure this has been the case every time I've seen it.

Comment: [`SELECT` still not broken.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `b` is nullable, this is not a bug. The problem is that SQL Server turns `NOT IN` into a series of `<> 1 AND <> 2 AND <> 3` etc. If you have `<> NULL`, that returns unknown, which in this case means false. In different scenarios this can qualify or disqualify *ALL* rows. Rather than the `LEFT JOIN` approach, you should say:

```
FROM dbo.OuterTable AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM x WHERE b = t.a);
```

Here is a quick demonstration:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(i INT);
INSERT @x VALUES(1),(2);

DECLARE @y TABLE(j INT);
INSERT @y VALUES(2),(NULL);

SELECT i FROM @x WHERE i NOT IN -- produces zero results
  (SELECT j FROM @y);

SELECT i FROM @x  AS x WHERE NOT EXISTS -- produces one result
  (SELECT 1 FROM @y WHERE j = x.i);
```

For a lot more details (and metrics to prove why `NOT EXISTS` is the best alternative):

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Also, please read this blog post by Gail Shaw:

http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/02/18/not-exists-vs-not-in/

Comment: Thanks. That's a good explanation and cutting out the nulls has fixed the problem. I can't see why it'd be desirable to have these scenarios in which all rows are disqualified though. Sure, some who understand that behaviour will make use of it but it's such a break from the general nature of the IN operator that it'd seem more sensible to require that behaviour to be invoked for explicitly.

Comment: @Adamantish You'll have to build a time machine and go back 20 years and convince them to alter the behavior, because this is the way the SQL standard has worked from the beginning (or at least since this syntax was introduced). If you don't like the behavior, you could always filter out NULLs first or not allow NULLs in that column in the first place.

Comment: @Adamantish - I tried to give an analogy [at the bottom of my answer here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48657/3690) explaining this. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks, yes it's helpful. I think the crucial stumbling block is that computers see the null as "value not known" whereas developers often use it to mean "value not necessary". I can see logically why it's important to enforce the first definition as it's the only one that's strictly true but still..
"I call it my billion-dollar mistake. It was the invention of the null reference in 1965." Tony Hoare (Inventor of QSort and other things)

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the behavior is well explained by Aaron. It can be resolved in more than one way, - LEFT JOIN, Filtering NULL values from inner query by filtering out them from where clause OR from select clause, using a co-related sub-query - to name a few.

Following post is a part of a case study on the same subject:- [NOT IN Subquery return zero rows -Workarounds](http://www.tectalks.com/598/not-in-subquery-alternatives/)